# Howto fix local audio output on HP convertible

Tags: sound

I installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my new convertible HP Elite x2 1012 G1. Audio is working over USB or over Bluetooth, but the local sound device is not working. "Dummy output" is shown only in the sound settings if no external sound devices are connected. How can I find out what to do?

That´s the output of `dmesg|grep snd`:

```
[    7.169377] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    7.169428] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    7.225743] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0: CX20724: BIOS auto-probing.
[    7.226331] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for CX20724: line_outs=1 (0x17/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    7.226335] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    7.226338] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x16/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    7.226340] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    7.226341] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    7.226344] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x1a
[    7.226346] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x19
[    7.227479] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0: Enable sync_write for stable communication
```

Comment: The Windows 10 device manager shows Conexant ISST Audio

Comment: With recently installed updates something changed. The loudspeakers are now working before I log in (I can hear the start sound). After login I can see _internal Audio_ now in the sound settings and all controls seems to work but there is still no sound from the speakers.

Answer (score 0):

In between I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 and had the same problem. Then I found out that squeezelight was causing the problem. After I have uninstalled squeezelight the local audio works correct.